# How to set MediaPlayerElement source in code in C++ in WinUI3?

Tags: c++, winui-3, mediaplayerelement

I am working on a simple project using WinUI3 in C++, and I want to  set `MediaPlayerElement` source in code. Microsoft provide the answers, but it is in c# as following code shows.

```cpp
MediaPlayerElement mediaPlayerElement1 = new MediaPlayerElement();
mediaPlayerElement1.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Media/video1.mp4"));
mediaPlayerElement1.AutoPlay = true;
```

So how to set the media source in code in C++? (the source is like this: `"rtsp://198.145.2.56"`)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Set the media source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement?view=winrt-22621#set-the-media-source),

> You can set it to a [MediaSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource?view=winrt-22621), [MediaPlaybackItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybackitem?view=winrt-22621), or
> [MediaPlaybackList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybacklist?view=winrt-22621).

There is a UWP [360VideoPlayback](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/bb470280e493a888d98ac367edf3b85f8c053c4f/Samples/360VideoPlayback/cpp/AppView.cpp#L110)(cpp) sample, which you can refer to.

```
MediaSource^ source = MediaSource::CreateFromUri(m_sourceUri);
m_mediaPlayer->MediaOpened += ref new TypedEventHandler<MediaPlayer^, Object^>(this, &AppView::OnMediaOpened);
m_mediaPlayer->Source = source;
```

Comment: This is C++/CLI, Microsoft promotes C++/WinRT instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt